# Chart.js <frame> or <iframe> elements do not have a title

Tags: javascript, iframe, chart.js

Using lighthouse on Chrome I got the error: `<frame> or <iframe> elements do not have a title`. After it I realized Chart.js creates a hidden iframe. I can't manage how to set the value of this iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a native solution but with jquery (or javascript) can be done.

Jquery

```
let wrapperId = '#wrapperId'
$(wrapperId)['0']._chartjs.resizer.title = `Some unique title`;
```